# Looping through Associative Array not working as expected?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a array like so and I am looping trough it like this:

```
$options = array();
$options[0] = 'test1';
$options[1] = 'test2';
$options[2] = 'test3';

foreach($options as $x)
{
  echo "Value=" . $x ;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

It outputs as expected:

```
Value=test
Value=test2
Value=test3
```

Now I want to add some options to my array and loop trough them:

```
$options = array();
$options['first_option'] = 'test';
$options['second_option'] = get_option('second_option');
$options['third_option'] = get_option('third_option');

foreach($options as $x)
{
  echo "Value=" . $x ;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

But it does not work as I want. Because it outputs:

```
Value=first_option
Value=second_option
Value=third_option
```

So now I do not know how to access stored values using **foreach** from these guys?
Something like:

```
Value=first_option='test'
```

So when I use `print_r($options)`

Output is:

```
Array
(
[first_options] => test
[second_option] => 
[third_option] => 
)
1
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `echo '<pre>',print_r($options),'</pre>';`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your loop should look like this:

```
foreach($options as $key => $val){
  echo "Val: ".$val;
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working just as expected and producing the desired result. You must have something else changing the values in `$options`. Correction: now that I see your edit, your functions are not returning any values, so options 1 and 2 are blank. Make sure that function returns something. Other than that, all of this code is good.

By the way, I recommend this:

```
$options = [
  'first_option' => 'test',
  'second_option' => get_option('second_option'),
  'third_option' => get_option('third_option')
];

foreach($options as $key) {
  echo "Value = {$key}<br>";
}
```

you can also use:

```
foreach($options as $key => $value) {
  echo "Value - {$value} = {$key}<br>";
}
```

or you could at least replace `array()` with just `[]`. Those are just some suggestions for neatness.